# jQuery binding : function runs before the event

Tags: jquery, events, binding

I am trying to understand event binding in jQuery. I have written a simple code as follows:

```
<html>

<script language="javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" name="bu1" value="click me">
</form>
</body>

<script language="javascript">
jQuery("input[type='button']").bind('click',alert('Hello'));
</script>


</html>
```

When I run the page, the alert happens on load rather than when I click the button. Can anyone help me to understand where is it I am going wrong?

Comment: You must provide a function, so wrap your alert inside function() {alert('hello');}

Comment: You are calling the function `alert` and passing the result to `.bind`... `functionName(arg1, arg2, ...)` calls a function immediately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery("input[type='button']").bind('click', function () {
    alert('Hello');
});
```

You need to pass a function, not call it. So in the code above I have added an anonymous function which calls alert.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. But If I need to give a function, then if I create function say function display(){alert("hello");} and then pass this function as jQuery("input[type='button']").bind('click',display()); still it is called on page load. What is the difference between passing a function and calling it?

Comment: if you do it like  `jQuery("input[type='button']").bind('click',display())` then `display` function will be immediately called and executed and will `return undefined` if you dont return something else yourself and `undefined` will be set as you event handler. It expects a function reference to be called later when that event occurs.

Comment: I just got it. I was using the function call instead of function reference. How silly of me! now when I type jQuery("input[type='button']").bind('click',display); it works fine. Thank you everybody!

Answer (score 0):

You should pass function as a second argument

```
jQuery("input[type='button']").bind('click', function() {
    alert('Hello')
});
```

Otherwise, javascript runs `alert('Hello')` to get value for second parameter of `bind` function, so you get alert displayed in your window.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript">
 jQuery(function(){
      jQuery("input[type='button']").bind('click',function(){
      alert('Hello')
   })
 })

</script>
```

Do inside

```
Jquery(function(){

})
```

and edit

```
 jQuery("input[type='button']").bind('click',function(){
          alert('Hello')
       })
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, wrap it up in a function, I also would add the event.preventDefault() as well:

```
jQuery("input[type='button']").bind('click', function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();        
  alert('Hello');
});
```

Rob